# How to copy one canvas into another canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have drawn some rects into a canvas and I want to copy those rects  into another canvas.The commonly discussed solution of using bitmaps will not work because I didn't use a bitmap in this canvas, no images only those rects.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please provide code so that we could recommend any alternative option. And also canvas always draws on bitmap but there is no method to get bitmap out of canvas.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried saving the attributes given to the rectangles upon drawing to the first canvas, and then redrawing them on the second canvas based on these attributes? Perhaps you could try creating a Rect-object for the first canvas and passing it to Canvas.drawRect() on the second canvas?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bitmap using a canvas and you draw on that bitmap.

```
bitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap(50,50,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
// drawn some rects into canvas
```

Now you can use the bitmap to draw on any canvas you want;

```
Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(bitmap);
Canvas canvas2 = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

Or if you have a canvas already:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

This way you draw rects only once and not on each canvas.

Comment: how can i decide the bitmap width and height to be the whole canvas if i have to decide them earlier?

Comment: You can use `createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)`

Comment: See also `canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)`. this draw the specified bitmap, scaling/translating automatically to fill the destination rectangle